# Tree display of a scope database with jinja and flask

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

```
Disclaimer: Title may not be the best way to describe what I am about to ask. If you have a better title in mind, please put it instead of mine
```

I am working on a `scope` database which will allow me to know what user has access to what ressource. To put it simply:

```
admin
     super-foo
          manager-foo-1
              user-1
              user-2
          manager-foo-2
              user-3
              user-4
     super-bar
          manager-bar-1
              user-5
              user-6
          manager-bar-2
              user-7
              user-8
```

`admin` has access to all users underneath him.

`super-foo` has access to all users underneath him, but not the ones of `super-bar`

etc... until your reach for example `user-1`, which doesn't have access to anything except himself

(when I say underneath, I mean hierarchically)
(when I say acces, I mean access data, the users, whatever)

Each entry of my DB is like this (using `manager-foo-1` for example):

```
id=manager-foo-1 (I have a function that I can call to get everything on the user as the uuid is the hash key of my user DB (because i'm using their usernames here, but the ids are uuids.))
parents_id=['super-foo']
children_id=['user-1', 'user2']
```

Here's my DB right now (I've replaced the `uuid4` with names):

```
for user_scope in UserScope.scan():
    print("User {} has parents {} and childs {}".format(user_scope.id, user_scope.parents_id, user_scope.children_id))

User manager-foo has parents [super-foo] and childs [user-1, user-2]
User admin has parents None and childs [super-foo]
User super-foo has parents [admin] and childs [manager-foo]
User user-1 has parents [manager-foo] and childs None
User user-1 has parents [manager-foo] and childs None
```

`childs` are set to `None` when you reach the bottom, but that shouldn't really matter

What I would like it to get a pretty display, or at least an understandable display or that DB, when given an id. So if given `admin`, display `EVERYTHING`. If given `user-1`, only display user-1 etc...

I've used a little bit of `jinja` templates but nothing advanced, the furthest I've got was this `for` loop to make a user list (using a macro)

```
  {% for user in user_list %}
   {% from "user_line.html" import user_line %}
   {{user_line(user)}}
  {% endfor %}
```

I'm having trouble to wrap my head around how to do this, what should the layout be, in what order should I display them and should I use macros? templates?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding a way to solve this.

First of all, I generated a dictionnary containing everything I need scopewise:

```
def get_all_children_tree(uid):
    scope = get_userscope_dict(user.client_id)

    children = []
    if scope['children_id'] is None:
        ret = {
            "user": scope['id'],
            "children": None
        }
        return ret

    for child_id in scope['children_id']:
        children.append(get_all_children_tree(child_id))

    ret = {
        "user": scope['id'],
        "children": children
    }
    return ret
```

This will give me something like this:

```
{
   'user':'cbf7f365-db8a-419b-9f8c-c24b2ce01361',
   'children':[
      {
         'user':'17bc0bdc-892b-4e47-b749-36c1687c0992',
         'children':[
            {
               'user':'d51056b7-60fe-437f-abe0-4a30076df4cd',
               'children':[
                  {
                     'user':'14f1963b-0f64-4431-a52f-819877d6096c',
                     'children':None
                  },
                  {
                     'user':'40765a8d-6001-4146-9d1f-ce3fd95646c7',
                     'children':None
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               'user':'8a617821-e189-4b17-ac67-597ca79b98e9',
               'children':[
                  {
                     'user':'42af51b0-2810-4004-b063-a4789631bb2e',
                     'children':None
                  },
                  {
                     'user':'26d43e72-4e45-40c3-ab2b-98c637dde5aa',
                     'children':None
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Then I wrote a jinja template like so :

```
{% extends "main.html" %}
{% block body %}
    <!-- tree -->
    <style type="text/css">
        ul.tree {
            overflow-x: auto;
            white-space: nowrap;
        }
        ul.tree,
        ul.tree ul {
            width: auto;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            list-style-type: none;
        }
        ul.tree li {
            display: block;
            width: auto;
            float: left;
            vertical-align: top;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        ul.tree ul li {
            background-image: url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODdhAQABAIABAAAAAP///ywAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=);
            background-repeat: repeat-x;
            background-position: left top;
        }
        ul.tree li span {
            display: block;
            width: 5em;
          /*
            uncomment to fix levels
            height: 1.5em;
          */
            margin: 0 auto;
            text-align: center;
            white-space: normal;
            letter-spacing: normal;
        }
        </style>
        <!--[if IE gt 8]> IE 9+ and not IE -->
        <style type="text/css">
        ul.tree ul li:last-child {
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          background-size:50% 1px;
          background-position: left top;
        }
        ul.tree ul li:first-child {
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          background-size: 50% 1px;
          background-position: right top;
        }
        ul.tree ul li:first-child:last-child {
          background: none;
        }
        ul.tree ul li span {
          background: url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODdhAQABAIABAAAAAP///ywAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=) no-repeat 50% top;
          background-size: 1px 0.8em;
          padding-top: 1.2em;
        }
        ul.tree ul {
          background: url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODdhAQABAIABAAAAAP///ywAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=) no-repeat 50% top;
          background-size: 1px 0.8em;
          margin-top: 0.2ex;
          padding-top: 0.8em;
        }
        </style>
        <!-- <[endif]-->
        <!--[if lte IE 8]>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            /* Just to simplify HTML for the moment.
             * This could easily be replaced by inline classes.
             */
            $(function() {
              $('li:first-child').addClass('first');
              $('li:last-child').addClass('last');
              $('li:first-child:last-child').addClass('lone');
            });
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
        ul.tree ul li {
          background-image: url(pixel.gif);
        }
        ul.tree ul li.first {
          background-image: url(left.gif);
          background-position: center top;
        }
        ul.tree ul li.last {
          background-image: url(right.gif);
          background-position: center top;
        }
        ul.tree ul li.lone {
          background: none;
        }
        ul.tree ul li span {
          background: url(child.gif) no-repeat 50% top;
          padding-top: 14px;
        }
        ul.tree ul {
          background: url(child.gif) no-repeat 50% top;
          margin-top: 0.2ex;
          padding-top: 11px;
        }
        </style>
        <[endif]-->

        <!-- page presentation -->
        <style type="text/css">
        body {
          font-family:sans-serif;
          color: #666;
          text-align: center;
        }
        A, A:visited, A:active {
          color: #c00;
          text-decoration: none;
        }
        A:hover {
          text-decoration: underline;
        }
        ul.tree,
        #wrapper {
          width: 960px;
          margin: 0 auto;
        }
        ul.tree {
          width: 650px;
        }
        p {
          margin-top: 2em;
        }
        </style>
    <div id="page-wrapper">
        <p> {{ data }}</p>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <ul class="tree">
                <li>
                    <span> {{ get_user(data['user']).username }}</span>
                    <ul>
                        {%- for child in data['children'] recursive %}
                            <li>
                                <span> {{ get_user(child['user']).username }} </span>
                                {%- if child['children'] -%}
                                    <ul>
                                        {{ loop(child['children']) }}
                                    </ul>
                                {%- endif %}
                            </li>
                        {%- endfor %}
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Here's the [final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqaKS.jpg)